# Building nginx on Ubuntu with cache_purge module - help?

Tags: server, compiling, gcc, nginx

I have been trying to rebuild nginx with cache_purge module from http://labs.frickle.com/.

I did the following and somehow the new build doesn't seem to include the module.

Here is what  I did:

Installed nginx

stopped it

installed build tools using:

```
aptitude -y install build-essential libc6 libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libssl0.9.8 libssl-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev lsb-base
```

Then :

```
cd /usr/src/
sudo wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.8.tar.gz
sudo wget http://labs.frickle.com/files/ngx_cache_purge-2.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf nginx-1.5.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf ngx_cache_purge-2.1.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.5.8
```

Then I did this:

```
sudo ./configure --add-module=/usr/src/ngx_cache_purge-2.1
```

The terminal sprouted a lot of things. Then I did:

```
sudo make && sudo make install
```

Finally though, when I do `nginx -V`, I don't see my module in the list. I see only this:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu) TLS SNI support enabled configure arguments: 
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre-jit 
--with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module 
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam 
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo 
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/module/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Can anybody help me understand if I did the build correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [easyengine](https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine) which install nginx(with cache purge module) php5-fpm mysql and postfix on one go.

Alternatively you can try ppa:rtcamp/nginx which install nginx with cache purge module.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:rtcamp/nginx 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx-custom
```